# UITableView custom cell Search results

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

How do I set the Search result to use my custom cell ?my custom works in the tableview and when I do a search it does search (i can see the log )but the cells are empty , I can click on the empty cell and it will segue to the next view controller.

If I use a normal Cell it works fine.

My code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SRMUserCell";

    UserViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UserViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UserDetails *userDetails = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        userDetails = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    } else {

        userDetails = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

    cell.username.text = userDetails.userName;
    cell.userMphone.text = userDetails.userMobile;
    cell.userML.text = userDetails.userML;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can assign separate tableviews & then make the check for the tag. Hopefully it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: After search are you reloading tableview?

Comment: @NuzhatZari I am using this method To reload the table - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString